# How to detect in ListView.Builder or GridView.Builder user finger is pointing at which index in Flutter Mobile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

I am using **ListView horizontal and vertical scrolling** and **MouseRegion or Inkwell(onHover method) any other way**  working properly on Flutter web And Desktop devices properly but not mobile devices (IOS and Android). I am trying to make listView and GridView auto play when it focuses on the particular index for a few mill-second and the video should play like **youtube app does video is hovered to** in list view and Instagram GridView post in the search bar.

Like the website used to auto preview of video at particular index

I need Your help..

Comment: Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package, you can provide your own area and check if it is within your bounded height to play video
https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list

Comment: I have looked into that but this is like marking your area if an item comes to position to the marked area then we perform the action but what if for my first and 2 last position that is impossible to focus? So like like youtube mobile app when we focus on that index it play video . and I combine of hrozontail listview and vertical listview